# Upload image from <input type="file" /> direct into web page without going via the server

Tags: javascript, html, input, image

Is it possible to upload an image from

```
<input type="file" />
```

straight into an HTML page (e.g. using Javascript) without first loading the image to the server?

I know I can do it with a bit of AJAX, but if I can avoid having to save the file to the server (to be cleaned up later), that'd be my preference.

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Nothing yet (beyond some googling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, client side javascript is not permitted to access the file system while running inside a browser.  If you did find some way getting a local file into a web page without first uploading it to the server, it would be considered a security hole and could be reported as a security bug against the browser that allowed it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much Ajax this actually uses, but it seems like it does the job you're asking for really well.
http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload